# Static class and members

Tags: c#

I have an assembly containing a public static class and members, it have a static constructor which initializes all the static members. When I load the assembly will all my members are loaded in memory, if yes then won't system give out of memory exception?

Comment: They will be initialized after first call to the class's members and they will be disposed once no resource has refence to the class.

Comment: @FCin static fields are rooted, so they won't be garbage collected; and things that *are* garbage collected are never "disposed" - they *might* be "finalized" (but that isn't guaranteed)

Comment: @MarcGravell So memory for static objects is never released? They will occupy memory even though there is no reference to them?

Comment: @FCin there's no such thing as a "static object" - those two terms are mutually exclusive; if you mean "static fields that point to objects" (i.e. static fields that are non-null references) - then the "object" that we are talking about is the object at the other end of the reference; there *is* a reference to them - the static field. Since static fields are retained for the duration of an app-domain, anything referenced by a static field will not be garbage collected.

Comment: @MarcGravell If I have static class and I make only one call to one of its members and never make a call to any of the members of the static class again, it will not be collected as long as app domain is alive? Good to know that, thank you for correcting me.

Comment: Yes @MarcGravell is absolutely right, static class and members are loaded in their app domain and never garbage collected, that's why I queried what happens if my static class have n number of members.

Answer (score 3):

a: static constructors aren't loaded just because you load an assembly; exactly when they *are* executed is complicated and depends on `beforefieldinit` and when the static fields look like they are going to be touched for the first time - but "at some point before they are first accessed" should cover it :)

b: are you using enough memory (in your static constructor) to cause an OOM? if you are: then yes! if not, then no! Usually, the answer will be "no". And if your static constructor does things like loading external data, then I'd argue that your static constructor is doing it wrong.

Note: when a static constructor fails, it is surfaced as a `TypeInitializationException`; the original cause will be the `.InnerException`.